# Reblog WordPress to another WordPress?

Tags: excerpt

1.Is there any way to reblog only the excerpts of WordPress posts to another WordPress with the featured image(option to choose the size of the image we prefer) and link to the WordPress site to see the full post from specific category/ies or tag/tags?

2.Will it cause me any problem to my page rank and the Google search results if I do something like this?

Comment: You have a very low answer acceptance rate; you need to go back through your past questions and accept correct answers. A very low acceptance rate makes other WP Answers users hesitant to help you. See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reblog WordPress to Tumblr?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48551/reblog-wordpress-to-tumblr)

Comment: @songdogtech I have voted the correct answers that were useful to me, what else do I have to do?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - RSS is the best way. See [FeedWordPress | simple and flexible Atom/RSS syndication for WordPress](http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/) and [WordPress › SimplePie Plugin for WordPress « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simplepie-plugin-for-wordpress/) and [Developer's Guide - Google AJAX Feed API - Google Code](https://developers.google.com/feed/)

2 - Probably

Comment: thnx for the infos :)